# Moving new folder to root

Tags: linux, .htaccess, directory

I have created a new website for a client, (joomla) which is currently running within a folder in the root called /new/ (original I know)

I am now trying to work out what would be the best way to switch over the sites, there are a lot of files (pdf's, doc's etc) so moving everything would take some time, plus the old site is very messy, and would also take some time to remove in one go.

What about htaccess, and having a redirect? I could then remove the old site and files from the root over time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be the use of [symbolic links](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-unixlinux-symbolic-soft-and-hard-links.html)(`ln -s` basically), but you won't be able to do that for files that have the same name in both root and your new/ subdirectory. You will encounter this same issue with apache redirects, thus basically, you need to decide before hand what do you want to serve from either root or new/ and resolve the possible conflicts.